# Sending a JPG Image from CSharp Windows Form application to ESP32 TCPIP Server

Tags: c#, tcp, esp32

I'm working on a project where I want to send a JPG image from my CSharp application to an ESP32. I want to be able to store the JPG image on an SD card on the ESP32 and then display the image on an ILI9341 TFT module.

In the CSharp application, I convert the image to a byte array as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image newImage = Image.FromFile("gargoyle_1.jpg");
    byte[] data = ImageClientModel.imageToByteArray(newImage);
    tcpFunctions.connect(config.EndPoint, config.Port, data);
}

internal static class ImageClientModel
{
    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(this System.Drawing.Image image)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

and then send it to the ESP32 using a class function:

```
public class tcpFunctions
{
    public static String connect(string ep, Int32 port, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ep, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Write(data);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            responseData = e.Message;
            return responseData;
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            responseData = e.Message;
            return responseData;
        }
        finally
        { //nothing
        }
    }
}
```

On the ESP32 side, I am receiving the data in the loop function as follows:

```
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();
  uint size=0;
  byte nString;
  File file;
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {      
      file = SD.open(imageFile, FILE_WRITE);
      while ((size = client.available())>0) {
        file.print(client.read());
      }      
      delay(10);       
    }
    file.close();
    Serial.println("File Closed");     
    client.stop();    
  }
}
```

At the moment, this just saves the byte array data to a file named "newImage.jpg" which isn't all that useful ... as it is a JPG in name only ... not format.

What I want to know, is how do I unscramble the egg and format the inbound byte array back to a JPG format to save as a usable image file?

Or am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Kind Regards

Comment: What is ImageClientModel and what does its imageToByteArray method do?

Comment: Soz ... I've added  the ImageClientModel.imageToByteArray function to the main question.

Comment: Note on the Arduino part: Use `write` instead of `print` to write data. While `print` will write the value of the data as text, `write` will write the actual data to the destination file.

Comment: NineBerry, you are a champion. Changing to write has solved the problem ... I can now transfer an image from CSharp client application to ESP32 TCPIP server like a bomb! Thank you so much for your time and patience ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open the jpeg file as a file stream and just copy the raw bytes over the network stream using the `CopyTo()` method.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("gargoyle_1.jpg"))
    {
        tcpFunctions.connect(config.EndPoint, config.Port, fileStream);
    }
}


public class tcpFunctions
{
    public static String connect(string ep, Int32 port, Stream data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ep, port))
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                data.CopyTo(stream);
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return "OK";
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need to change the format of the data to send it. Just keep the jpeg format and send the image in jpeg format.

Always use streams when working with potentially large files. When converting the data from a stream into a byte array, you need large chunks of memory which might not be available.

Comment: Thanks NineBerry ... I'll give that a go.

Comment: Nah, the file still ends up as a non JPG file. If I open it in NotePad, it's just a set of numbers. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: See my comment to your question.